# independence of chi square distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

We already knew that if two independent chi-squared random variables, then their sum is also chi-squared with the degree of freedoms is the sum of theirs. How about the converse?

If $X\sim\chi^2(n)$ and $Y\sim\chi^2(m)$ and their sum $X+Y\sim\chi^2(n+m)$, can we conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables?

Thank you

Comment: What don't you use simply the definition ? What mean $X\sim\chi^2(n)$ ? $Y\sim\chi^2(m)$ ? And thus, what up if $X+Y\sim \chi^2(n+m)$ ?

Comment: i am sorry if I didnt make it clear, $X\sim\chi^2(n)$ means the random variable $X$ has chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, so does $Y\sim\chi^2(m)$, and so does $X+Y\sim\chi^2(n+m)$, means $Y$ and $X+Y$ have chi-squared distribution with $m$ and $n+m$ degrees of freedom, respectively,

any idea to solve the problem? I cannot use just the definition."